# What does <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> actually do in .NET Core 3+?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Recently, I've read about [Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) and I'm wondering:

1. How is it working under the hood?
2. Are there any drawbacks or caveats that I should take into account when adding `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`?

For example, I'd created a simple console application and published it with `self-hosted` options. The output size was on 20mb greater with `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /` even If I don't explicitly use any of `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages

Comment: You can read about it here -> https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-new-project-file-program-and-the-generic-host-in-asp-net-core-3/#the-new-project-file-and-changes-to-the-shared-framework

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The shared framework is a collection of assemblies that is included in the runtime and as such does not need to be resolved individually through NuGet. You can think of it as a NuGet package though, because the handling is very similar. The primary difference of course is that it doesn’t need to be downloaded from NuGet because it is available locally with the runtime.

Since it is distributed with the runtime, that also means that you cannot reference a specific version of it. Instead, you always get the version that is included in the available version of the runtime. This has the benefit that the contents will automatically update when the runtime is updated, so your application that depends on one of the shared frameworks will also just roll forward at runtime.

1. Attempting to answer that in detail is out of the scope of a Stack Overflow answer since this is some deep MSBuild logic. If you are interested to find out, you can checkout the [dotnet/sdk repo](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk) though which contains everything that makes the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` project SDK and its subtypes work, including the `FrameworkReference` implementation.
2. First of all you should know that there is no way to use e.g. ASP.NET Core without using that framework reference. So it’s not like you have much of a choice. Most of the time, you won’t be adding the framework reference yourself though; ASP.NET Core applications use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` project SDK which already includes the framework reference by default. You will only need to add the framework reference yourself if you want to add ASP.NET Core references in a non-Web project (for example in a class library for ASP.NET Core).

   Apart from that, there aren’t many things you will have to keep in mind though. Just remember not to use a version and keep your SDK and runtime updated to make sure that you have all the latest security patches.

Comment: I've played with `self-contained` `dotnet publish` and what I noticed that output size is bigger on 20mb  with `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` even If I don't explicitly use any of `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages. Do you know why?

Comment: @ЯрославВиталиевич Hm, that’s odd. I was under the impression that the unused assemblies would be trimmed out of the box. Apparently that’s not the case right now. I’ve removed the paragraph from my answer until I am able to clarify that..

Comment: @poke If we reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in a .NET 6 class library, and some code in the library uses it, does the ASP.Net runtime always have to be installed, or only if those methods that use ASP.Net API's will get used? I'm wondering if the app that uses the library will fail to start if ASP.Net runtime isn't installed.

Comment: I'm answering my question: if the ASP.NET runtime is referenced by a class library or console app, and the computer doesn't have the ASP.NET runtime installed, as long as the app doesn't use any methods that use the ASP.NET API's (example: methods from the class library that use the ASP.NET API's), the consuming app will start and work fine.

Comment: Why not use a version? As far as I know, the Version attribute only specifies a minimum version, e.g. to exclude buggy or vulnerable runtime versions. Currently, the latest version is 2.2.8, I think, which is different from the NET 6.x, 7.x versions.

Comment: OK, seems I confused something: _Version_ attribute for minimum version was when referencing specific packages via _PackageReference_ (also `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` before _FrameworkReference_ was introduced?), but it is not to be used with _FrameworkReference_.

Comment: @ErikHart Yeah, `PackageReference` references a NuGet package that has a version; `FrameworkReference` references a part of the framework that ships with .NET. So this cannot have a version since it will always use the version that ships with the runtime. The [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/) is from the old time before the framework reference was a thing and is nowadays only used to run ASP.NET Core on the legacy .NET Framework (since ASP.NET Core 2.1 (not 2.2) is still supported there).

Comment: @poke Interesting, 2.2 not supported... We have a number of AspNetCore 2.2.x packages referenced for netstandard2.0, to use with .NET Framework. Just legacy, if somebody still needs it with old code. Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0` has vulnerabilities (or better: vulnerable IIS runtime parts existed) and isn't fixed, but 2.1 has a later, fixed version 2.1.7.