# How to use the ASP.NET Core shared framework correctly or how to use its assemblies on their own?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

#### The situation

In our application we have a **WPF client** and an **ASP.NET Core server**, both of which uses **.NET 5**.

We store all our DLLs on *server* and the *client* downloads all the necessary DLLs from server when user logs in. Originally, the *client* has been independent of any third-party libraries, our other projects, etc. which allowed us, in certain situations, to download the *client* as DLL (using another application – which I will be calling a *loader* – specifically designed for this purpose), load the *client* using `Assembly.Load(binaryData)` and execute the login method.

**Side note:** *What has been so far referred to as *client* is actually just a simple application which authenticates the user and downloads the DLLs for the actual **client** which consists of multiple assemblies and allows us to work with the data on server. For the sake of simplicity, however, I won't distinguish between them as they both stand on the client side.*

Recently, I've implemented single sign-on using OpenID Connect based on [NetCoreConsoleClient sample](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/NetCoreConsoleClient/src/NetCoreConsoleClient) from [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel) and, as a result, a few references to other assemblies have been added to the *client*. Now, in order for the SSO to work, the *loader* has to download these assemblies together with the *client*.

#### The problem

Currently, the *client* uses some of the assemblies from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** shared framework. According to [this SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478618/what-frameworkreference-include-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-is-actually-do-in) it should be working on my machine since the runtime is installed – the framework is present on my machine in: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\5.0.0`. However, when I try logging in using the *client* downloaded via *loader* I'm getting ***System.IO.FileNotFoundException:** 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'*

Also, if I take the DLL from the path mentioned above and try to load the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting** assembly manually, using `Assembly.Load(binaryData)`, I'm getting ***System.BadImageFormatException:** 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)'*

I tried searching online and discovered that it might be caused by 32-bit/64-bit architecture conflict. I tried creating a simple demo application where I tried changing between the architectures but had no success.

I also have found a few mentions of the exception I'm getting when loading the assembly manually but none of them seems to be relevant for my specific case.

#### The questions

Am I using the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** shared framework wrong? How to use it properly?

Is there a way how to actually use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting** and other assemblies from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** as a regular DLL so that I can load them using `Assembly.Load(binaryData)`?

Comment: Open a visual studio command prompt and launch `fuslogvw`. Check the settings and enable logging for failed binds. Re-run your application and you should see a list of locations the framework is searching when trying to bind your DLLs. That should give you some more diagnostic information. See https://www.hanselman.com/blog/back-to-basics-using-fusion-log-viewer-to-debug-obscure-loader-errors (Don't forget to turn logging back off afterwards, or you'll have a hard to track down performance hit on all .Net apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, we have been able to figure it out.

The *client* references **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** and **Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App** and the *loader* has to reference them as well since the *client* DLL is loaded using `Assembly.Load(binaryData)` inside it.

This is something I have completely missed but was as easy to fix as adding the following piece of markup to the *loader* project file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That makes sense. When framework dependent deployment is used, your app relies on runtime configuration files like `*.runtimeconfig.json` to see where to locate dependencies (no GAC in .NET Core). Without proper `FrameworkReference` in project file, the runtime configuration files might not contain the necessary elements.

Comment: I have this exact problem, except we have no control over the loader. I really wish they allowed us to build the AspNetCore dlls to the output folder...