# ASP.NET Core application compiles but can't load Microsoft.AspNetCore at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-management

I have a class library project targeting .NET 7 which needs to self-host ASP.NET Core Web API.

I added a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework:

```
<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
```

as well as some `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` nuget packages. In project dependencies list I see that framework assemblies are properly found and resolved from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref\7.0.5\ref\net7.0\\`:

[image]

The project compiles with no issues. I see that dlls from nuget packages are copied to the binary output folder, while framework dlls no. This is probably correct.

When I run the application I get an exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

If, just to check, I manually copy the dll to the output folder, the exception disappears. Obviously it doesn't find framework dlls at runtime.

Does anyone know what the reason could be, and what is the proper approach to shared framework dependencies management?

UPD:
I digged into the code deeper (it is originally not mine and gets into net 4 times) and it is trickier than originally looks.
The console executable in its config file has a custom config section. So far so good, but the section has a field of type Type. Which in a config file refers to a fully quantified type name mentioning the assembly in a binary folder. Which is loaded when configuration is loaded and the Type object is created. I guess Type.GetType method loads it. That assembly directly references the assembly in question which at this moment is loaded too. This all goes flawlessly but at a certain moment a method is called which needs objects from Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages which in turn reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll from a framework which at that moment it can't find. And it explodes. But if the framework dll is in a binary folder - no pb.

I still don't understand how framework dlls should be treated. In many places it is said: "consider them like nuget packages, but local, no need to download". But in this case I may need to copy them locally. Do I?

Comment: How do you run the app? What app do you run?

Comment: It is a console app which loads this class library.

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce your issue, could you pls share more details? I created a .net 7 console app and a .net 7 class library, I added project reference, I also installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` nuget package in the console app. Then when I run the console app, no error appeared.

Comment: I updated the question, it is too long for a comment. Things are a bit trickier than it originally looked.

Comment: @phuzi It is a project targeting two frameworks. But we are talking about net 7 build here.

Comment: Ok, the issue is resolved using this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951383/how-to-use-the-asp-net-core-shared-framework-correctly-or-how-to-use-its-assembl
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved using this question:

[How to use the ASP.NET Core shared framework correctly or how to use its assemblies on their own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951383/how-to-use-the-asp-net-core-shared-framework-correctly-or-how-to-use-its-assembl)

The dll was loaded dynamically and in this case in is obviously necessary to add a framework reference to the loader application to make framework assemblies available.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an C++/CLI Project (only .Net 6 as Target) depending on a C# ASP.NET Core library.

The C++/CLI Project was not able to recognice the dependencies of my C# Project and was thus not able to create the correct .runtimeconfig.json. Since the runtime Dependencies were not correct.

The Documentation regarding the behaviour of the file was helpful to understand the Problem [runtimeconfig.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli).

My solution was to add the relevant information to a runtimeconfig.template.json File in the Project-Directory of my C++/CLI-Project. The Discription on how to do that is mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/).

My new runtimeconfig.template.json:

```
{
    "frameworks": [
        {
            "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
            "version": "6.0.0"
        }
    ]
}
```